# Align-like environment in a column of array

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, arrays

I have an `array` in which one of the columns is a polynomial, and I would like to align the terms of the polynomial for each row of the array.
My hack is to use `\phantom`s all over the place, but is there a way to do this automatically?  For instance, if I could make this part of the array act like some sort of `align` environment?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

What I have:
\[ \begin{array}{|r|c|}
\hline
S & P(x) \\ 
\hline
9 & x + x^2 + x^3 \\
10 & 3x + x^2 + x^3 \\
11 & x + 10x^3\\
\hline
\end{array} \]

What I want:
\[ \begin{array}{|r|c|}
\hline
S & P(x) \\ 
\hline
9 & \phantom{3}x + x^2 + \phantom{10}x^3 \\
10 & 3x + x^2 + \phantom{10}x^3 \\
11 & \phantom{3}x \phantom{{} + x^2 } + 10x^3\\
\hline
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have vs. what I want]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use more columns like

```
\[ \begin{array}{|r|r@{{}+{}}c@{{}+{}}r|}
\hline
S & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{P(x)} \\
\hline
9  & x                      & x^2   &x^3 \\
10 & 3x                     & x^2   & x^3 \\
11 &  \mc{x} &       & 10x^3\\
\hline
\end{array} \]
```

where `\mc` is defined to take care of alignment without the succeding `+` sign.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{${}+{}$}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r@{\hspace{\mylen}}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

What I have:
\[ \begin{array}{|r|c|}
\hline
S & P(x) \\
\hline
9 & x + x^2 + x^3 \\
10 & 3x + x^2 + x^3 \\
11 & x + 10x^3\\
\hline
\end{array} \]

What I want:
\[ \begin{array}{|r|r@{{}+{}}c@{{}+{}}r|}
\hline
S & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{P(x)} \\
\hline
9  & x                      & x^2   &x^3 \\
10 & 3x                     & x^2   & x^3 \\
11 &  \mc{x} &       & 10x^3\\
\hline
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is so simple!  It is almost exactly what I had in mind, except that there are now too many +-signs.  In my actual document this would cause several unnecessary pluses to be added back-to-back, as in x + + + + x^5.

Comment: @CoreyHarris See the update please.

Comment: This seems to work.  I replaced the \mc command with \newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{r@{\hspace{\mylen}}}{#2}} so I can do \mc{3}{x^3} etc.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @CoreyHarris Glad it worked. You may do `\newcommand{\mc}[2][1]{\multicolumn{#1}{r@{\hspace{\mylen}}}{#2}}` so that `\mc{x}` can also be used.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem I need to solve is a little more complicated... some of the equations may have minus signs instead of plus signs (e.g. the last equation might be $x-10x^3$).  Is there a simple extension of this solution, or should I modify the question / ask a new one?

Comment: @CoreyHarris You can define another `\mc` like command (say `\mymc` ) where instead of  `@{\hspace{\mylen}}}` (before `r` ofcourse) you add `@{{}-{}}` and use it like `\mymc{10x^3}`

Comment: Ah thanks... It looks like it actually has to be `@{\hspace{-\mylenplus}{}-{}}r`.  Otherwise it gives a plus sign followed immediately by a minus sign.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @CoreyHarris Define `\newcommand{\mymc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r@{{}-{}}}{#1}}` and use it in the previous column like `11 &  \mc{x} &   \mymc{}    & 10x^3\\ `. However, if the previous column is not empty, you have to define yet another macro like `\newcommand{\myplusmc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r@{{}+{}}}{#1}}` and use `11 &  \myplusmc{x} &   \mymc{5x^2}    & 10x^3\\ `. Well, life is getting complicated.